# Should a class have a "has-a" relationship with a configuration class?

Tags: dependency-injection

I have seen some questions about wrapping a set of configuration properties in a class, but not how to actually use it. Given a configuration class (omitting getters and setters for brevity):

```
class ServiceConfiguration {
    private String foo;     
}
```

Should the service class use the configuration directly?

```
static class SomeServiceB {
    private ServiceConfiguration configuration;

    public SomeServiceB(ServiceConfiguration configuration) {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void printIt() {
        System.out.println(configuration.getFoo());
    }
}
```

Or should it only be concerned with the actual value of foo? For example:

```
static class SomeServiceA {
    private String foo;

    public SomeServiceA(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public void printIt() {
        System.out.println(foo);
    }
}
```

I would argue that the SomeServiceA is superior because of the lower coupling and separation of concerns.

Comment: It's a fair question, but off-topic on SO because it is fundamentally opinion-based.

Comment: If `ServiceConfiguration` is mutable and you want the services to reflect any changes, the latter would require manual synchronization. If you need to access multiple fields, the latter would be more cumbersome. If it's just pulling a single immutable value, then it's a matter of opinion.

Comment: @SeanVanGorder Putting mutability to the side, I would still argue that it isolates change. Lets say that several services use _ServiceConfiguration_ in my application, and the application uses Spring Java configuration. So in my Spring config class I have methods like `@Bean SomeServiceA getA() { return new SomeServiceA(conf.getFoo()); }`. If I were to rename the getter in the configuration class then all services classes would have to change, instead of just the one Java configuration class.

Comment: That `conf.getFoo()` call in your Spring config class would need to change as well, along with any other code that constructs service classes that need this value. Plus, if you're renaming the `foo` field in the configuration class, you'll probably want to rename the `foo` field and constructor parameter in the service class, too.

Comment: I would not tag `java` here. It really does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions are correct. The important part is that a class only takes a dependency on configuration values that it actually uses.

This means that injecting an `ApplicationConfiguration` object that holds all configuration values, or allows access to all application configuration values is a bad idea, because this makes it unclear what configuration values the class actually uses and postponing the reading of configuration values can cause configuration mistakes to only pop up very late. The mantra is: fail-fast.

Injecting an object that encapsulates the values a class needs is typically more convenient than injecting all those values in separate constructor arguments. This is basically the [Parameter Object refactoring](https://refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html).

Another advantage of wrapping configuration values (even if it is just one) into a Parameter Object, is that it allows a DI Container to auto-wire this class. This is especially useful when the class has dependencies other than configuration values. For instance:

```
class SomeServiceB {
    public SomeServiceB(IDep1 d1, IDep2 d2, SomeServiceConfig config) {
    }
}
```

Primitive values can't easily be auto-wired by a DI Container, because values like strings and integers are ambigious: you might have multiple instances of these values with total different meanings. For instance, you might have both a connection string and a file path. Both are strings.

It is important though to make the configuration objects immutable to communicate clearly that they can't be changed. You should typically construct them at application startup and register them as singleton.